# Mongodb: db.collection.update is not working

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I want to replace an Object "habit" with other Object. For example, I want to replace habit:{1:{"name":"drink water", record:[[0],[1]]}} to habit:{1:{"name":"drink water", record:[[0],[1]]}, 2:{"name":"stretching", "record":[[0],[1]]}}.

```
var User=require("mongoose").model("User"); //user schema
...
router.post('/', async (req,res,next)=>{ //req: {username, total, board:{index:{habitname, record:[[날짜, 요일, check]...]}}}
    console.log("backedn board");

    var username=req.body.username;
    var habit_list=req.body.board;
    console.log(req.body.board);    

    var info=req.body;
   //mongodb: {username, password, habit:{1:{}, 2:{}}}
    try{
       //const user=await User.findOne({username:username});
       User.update({'username':username}, {'habit':habit_list});
       console.log("update user habit!");
       res.send(info);
   }
    catch(error){
        console.log("fail to save data")
       res.send(error);
   }
```

But it does not work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$set` operator in update object.

For ex.

```
User.update({'username':username}, {$set: {'habit':habit_list}});
```

For more detail please check in here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/